# MapView in xaml

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime

I want to create Mapview control in xaml as below but I get an error "The name Mapview does not exist in namespace http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">
    <esri:Map Background="White" Name="mainDisplay" WrapAround="True" IsLogoVisible="False" 
          UseAcceleratedDisplay="False">
...
...
    </esri:Map>
</esri:MapView>
```

The only reason to add Mapview is to know where the user has clicked on the map by its MapViewTapped MapViewInputEventArgs.location. Please note that the ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.dll is added in my project - References.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF. Actually, there is no `MapView` object in it.
The `MapView` object is in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET, you will find `MapView.MapViewTapped` Event in [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/phone/api-reference/html/E_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Controls_MapView_MapViewTapped.htm). Instead, you can use [OnMouseDown or TouchDown](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/index.html?ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map_members.html) event in ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF.